# laravel ajax not entering success function

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

first let me share some code:

**View / Form:**

```
 <form id="xlsForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <input class="btn btn-primary" id="loadFile" type="file" name="excelfile" accept=".xls,.xlsx,.docx,.doc" required/>
            <input type ="hidden" name="load" value="0">
            <button  class="btn btn-light" name ="loadSubmit" id="loadSubmit" type="submit" value ="Analyze">Analyze</button>
        </form
```

> 

**JQuery**

```
 $('#xlsForm').submit(function uploadFile(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
            }
        });

        $('#loader').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('ExcelToArray')}}",
            method: 'POST',
            data: new FormData(this),
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("entered response")
                $("#inner").empty();
                $.each(response.like_values, function (index, value) {
                    $("#inner").append
                    ('<div class="row">' +
                        '<div class="col-xs-6">' +
                        '<input class="' + value + '" data-name="' + value + '" type="number" name="weight[' + value + ']" min="1" max="3" value="1" style="text-align:center"> ' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="col-xs-6"  style="padding-left: 9px">' +
                        '<input type="checkbox"  data-name="' + value + '" class="checkbox" value="' + value + '" name="checkbox[' + value + ']"  checked >  ' +
                        '<label style="color:' + response.color[value] + '; font-weight: bold" for="skillChoice_' + index + '">' + value + ' </label>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>');
                });

            },
           error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('jqXHR is : ' + jqXHR.value
                         + 'textStatus is : ' + textStatus
                         + ' errorThrown is : ' + errorThrown);

            },

          complete: function () {

              console.log("entered complete")
                $('#loader').hide();
                load_employees()

            },
        });


    });
```

In my controller there is a lot of stuff which i will not share because this code

```
  return response()->json([
         'like_values' => $like_values,
         'color' => $color,]);
```

at the end of my controller function is working and in chrome i can see the data available:
[like_values and color in my chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHy9s.png)

My problem is that my success function is not being called and the arrays are not being iterated. However it used to work but i don't know whats the problem now. I am getting an error (which i remember it used to work even with this error. I used to ignore it but it says :

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0

Maybe i am missing something related to this error.

Does anyone has a clue whats wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to pass your ```$like_values``` with json_encoded and at blade use ```split``` function and then try to iterate.

Comment: Hi @Ali when i do that it just sends it encoded to my view. Rember please that the success function is not being called at all. Even if i just put an `alert` function. i dont think my problem is related to any variable or encoding, beause the data is there and if it would call the `success` funcion the variables would be processed, but its not entering the success function at all.

Comment: Have you tried while removing ```contentType: false,cache: false,processData: false,``` and checked ?

Answer (score 0):

JSON Syntax Rules state that data should be separated by commas however you added an extra comma in your return keyword to end your controller function.

Change this:

```
  return response()->json([
     'like_values' => $like_values,
     'color' => $color,]);
```

To:

```
  return response()->json([
         'like_values' => $like_values,
         'color' => $color]);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I removed that comma but unfortunatly it didnt change anything.

Answer (score 0):

i've found the issue. If you see the response in the screenshot i made, you can see also the output : `string(15) xlsx ausgelöst`. So i was also doing a `var_dump()` in my controller. So this string was not in json format this is why it was never going to my `success function`. Actually i never knew that everything which i send from controller to my view will be evaluated by `ajax`. I thought its only this code.

```
 return response()->json([
     'like_values' => $like_values,
     'color' => $color]);
```

which will be considered.

However after removing the `var_dumps()` from controller it worked fine, it was only my actual response data which were sent to the view and ajax recognized it as json and `success:` function was executed.

Thanks to yall anyway.